# Having UIPickerView displayed when button is tapped

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

The header explains completely what I try to manage at this time. Being short, I liked the example from [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPoSwzH2J_s&list=UUANsW00CkQnNnnUyuC1cygw&index=4&feature=plcp). There's only one problem, in this example is used UIDatePicker instead of ordinary UIPickerView. My problem is that I can't input my UIPickerView with data from NSMutableArray. I tried to accomplish it in common way using three essential methods to make the 'drum' running.

Now in viewDidLoad :self.uiPickerViewData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"One",@"Two", nil];

```
//when tapping on Set Quality button
- (IBAction)setQuality:(id)sender 
{

actionSheet=[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
[actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleDefault];

CGRect pickerFrame=CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0);
qualityPicker=[[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
qualityPicker.delegate=self;
[actionSheet addSubview:qualityPicker];

[qualityPicker release];

UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, actionSheet.bounds.size.width, 44)];
[toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
[toolBar sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem *spacer=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *setButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Set" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(setQualityIntoDB)];
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel)];

[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer,setButton,cancelButton, nil]animated:NO];
[spacer release];
[setButton release];
[cancelButton release];

[actionSheet addSubview:toolBar];
[toolBar release];

[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
}
```

And essentials which didn't bring me expected result.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
   return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   return [uiPickerViewData count];
}

-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return [uiPickerViewData objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
// Will be properly implemented later

DBAccess *access=[[DBAccess alloc]init];
[access closeDataBase];
[access release];
}
```

I am getting UIPickerView empty. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use this methods here after creating a picker and a toolbar out of the visibility under the view (coordinates = (0,640)):

```
- (void)showPicker{

[UIView beginAnimations:@"picker" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    picker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,- pickerHeight);
    pickerToolbar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, - pickerHeight - toolbarHeight);

[UIView commitAnimations];  }

-(void)hidePicker{
[UIView beginAnimations:@"picker" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

picker.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
pickerToolbar.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

[UIView commitAnimations]; }
```

then add showPicker as action for your button and hidePicker as action for something else you want..

Comment: Will it populate my UIPickerView, or it will only animate nicely open/close operations?

Comment: They are open close operations.. Sorry, i thought that the question was the title. The only reason for the unpopulated picker is that uiPickerViewData is empty or deallocated. You can create an NSArray in  the class interface, allocate it in -(void)viewDidLoad method and release it in -(void)viewDidUnload

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{     PickerList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            SecondPickerList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"0.0 cm",@"0.1 cm",@"0.2 cm",@"0.3 cm",@"0.4 cm",@"0.5 cm",@"0.6 cm",@"0.7 cm",@"0.8 cm",@"0.9 cm", nil];        

            for(int i=0;i<210;i++)
            {

                [PickerList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i cm",i]];
            }
  [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

i mean you must alloc your Mutablearray in didload or in App Delegate...

Comment: And keep this array in memory the whole way long until ViewController will get released?

Comment: Yes.It depends on how big is you'r array... you can alloc it when you enter in your view controller where the PickerController is situated  and release when you'r getting back from it. Sorry for my english..

Comment: and if it's not working try to update all the components...    [Picker reloadAllComponents];